# CSS img:after not working on Coppermine

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

I was trying to add a CSS style in my Coppermine Gallery but It doesn't work. Here's the code I want to apply to the gallery thumbnails.

```
.image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.image-wrap:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: solid 1px #1b1b1b;

    -wekbit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.image-wrap img {
    vertical-align: bottom;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);

    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

The pseudo-classes for image links are a little bit weird to apply the image-wrap:after stylesheet and I went a little bit messy trying to figure out how to apply it. Here's the code I ended up writing for **a:link .image{**

```
/* pseudo-classes for image links */
a:link .image{
    vertical-align: bottom;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.4);

    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}


a:after .image{
        content: ' ';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    border: solid 1px #1b1b1b;

    -wekbit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.4), inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;

}
```

[Here's my gallery.](http://danithemes.fanscity.eu/designs/) How can I do to make the CSS style work? **THANK YOU SO MUCH! *I love coding but sometimes it turns a little bit hard.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll gladly help, but i don't understand what you're trying to do here. Can we have an image of the result you want to get ?

Anyway, some general advices :

- you don't need prefixes on border-radius and box-shadow anymore
- you don't need to specify :link on a link tag.
- consider using "top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;" rather than width and height 100%.

---

**Edit:** Okay, now with your picture i understand.

So, the problem is here :

```
a:after .image {...}
```

Doing so, you don't target the :after pseudo-element, but a .image element wich would be child of it. So it's nonsense. What you should do is add a class on the link itself (if possible) or target it more precisely using selectors, and just work on this :after pseudo-element.

I'll make you an example if this isn't enough to help you. :)

---

**Edit:** Okay, i made an example anyway: http://jsfiddle.net/Manumanu/gon7kooa/
And if you wish to use it with hover: http://jsfiddle.net/Manumanu/gon7kooa/2/

Comment: Thanks! Something like [this](http://webdesignerwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/image-wrap-after.jpg)

Comment: Okay, i just edited my post here to point out the problem. If you need more help, i'll make an example.

Comment: I made examples anyway, you can check my post ;)

Comment: I still can't figure it out, but thanks anyway! I'll try another examples and yours again till I get it. Thanks again!!!

Comment: To make it clear, if you use "foo .bar {}", you'll target the .bar element, that is foo's child, not foo itself. if you go "foo:after .bar {}", you'll target a .bar element that's child of the peudo-element "after" of a foo element (not directly foo's child). But a pseudo-element can't have any child, so it'll never find anything matching in your html. Moreover, the "content" property is supposed to work directly on :after/:before.